# What is the difference between "com.google.android.gms..." and "com.google.firebase..." in the gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, admob

What is the difference between "com.google.android.gms..." and "com.google.firebase..." in the gradle?

Implementing cloud messaging and admob. What's the difference between the libraries below?

When Implementing Cloud Messaging

1. com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0
2. com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0

When Implementing admob

1. com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0
2. com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.0.0

two api sites. What is the difference?

1. https://console.developers.google.com/apis
2. https://console.firebase.google.com

Does firebase mean the latest version?

Comment: play-services-gcm is deprecated you has to migrate to firebase

Comment: Thanks Amir Abbas.

"https://console.developers.google.com/apis" is deprecated too?

Comment: i think it's just about gcm. but i suggest firebase. it's more integrated.